# How to use the .sty file on a webpage

Tags: packages, installing

There are webpages that contains .sty text file. Does anyone know how to use it?

Thanks for any helpful answers.

Comment: Usually this means that your browser decided to display the file as plain text instead of downloading it.

Answer (score 9):

I think you need to be more specific. Generally, `.sty` is the extension of LaTeX packages. To use `package.sty` you put

```
\usepackage{package}
```

in the preamble of your document. In order for this to work the .sty file must be installed in a place where LaTeX can find it. In the simple case where the package needs no support files this could be the directory with your document or in a local texmf tree.

In more complicated cases you need to install all files according to their types. See [Where to install packages](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-install-where) for details.

However, if you are using one of the big TeX distributions, e.g. MiKTeX or TeXlive, chances are that you can install the package using the distribution package manager. This will ensure that you get an up-to-date version and that the package and support files will be correctly installed.

Comment: Should I copy the style text and save it in a a file of some format? Thanks!

Comment: .sty files are plain text files; you could copy the info into a text editor and save with a name ending in .sty, but it's usually easier just just to right click on the link to the .sty file in your browser and choose the option "Save Link As.." or "Save Target As.."